# Python - Filter a dict JSON response to send back only two values or convert to a string?

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, filter

I am manipulating a URL in Python that calls an API and gets a valid result in JSON.

I only need the 'latitude' and 'longitude' provided by [result]

But, I cannot seem to find any good way to handle sending dict values back.

I've tried to convert the JSON to a string, but as my end goal is to append the latitude and longitude to another URL, this seems silly?

Have been searching around, and seems parsing DICT a common issue.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My code (that ran)

```
import urllib2
import json
Postcode = raw_input("Hello hello hello, what's your postcode..?  ")
PostcodeURL = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/' + Postcode
json_str = urllib2.urlopen(PostcodeURL).read()
d = json.loads(json_str)
print(d)
```

The output looks like this:

```
{u'status': 200, u'result': {u'eastings': 531025, u'outcode': u'N8', u'admin_county': None, u'postcode'
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a nested dictionary back, so access it's values using the right keys:

```
d = json.loads(json_str)
lat, long = d['result']['latitude'], d['result']['longitude']
newurl = url + '?' + 'lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access your JSON object exactly like a dictionary.  So to get the latitude and longitude from your result, you can use:

`lat, long = d[result][latitude], d[result][longitude]`

Load these into strings, do your error checking, and then append them into your new URL.